# Logstash Unrecognized service Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-linux, logstash

I have been following this tutorial to install ELK stack in a remote server which runs on Amazon Linux.
https://www.aytech.ca/blog/setup-elk-stack-amazon-linux/
I was able to install Elasticsearch and then to start it as a service.Then I installed logstash. However when I try to start the logstash service using this command,

```
service logstash status
```

the console returns this error.

```
 logstash: unrecognized service
```

However, when I grep'd the logstash it gave this output. Means it is running,right?
[image]

Can someone provide a solution how to make this logstash run as a service?

[image]

Comment: so the similar command `service elasticsearch start` worked just fine?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I added a screenshot of outputs to those two commands to the question.

Comment: This guide might refer to Amazon Linux 1 and if you launched an instance recently you might have launched Amazon Linux 2, can you try running `systemctl status logstash` and see what is the output in that case.

Comment: @Yaron I tried running that and it gave me -bash: systemctl: command not found.

Comment: @Yaron the version is 2018.03. Means it's Amazon Linux 1.

Comment: is there anything logstash-related in /etc/init.d?

Comment: Yaron & Jeff , thank you for the suggestions. I had to relaunch the server with AL 2 as the OS and now logstash is running in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I had to relaunch the server with Amazon Linux 2 OS.Now I am able to run Logstash inside that,but I still don't know how to tackle the issue in an Amazon Linux 1 OS.